# OnTouchListener on Android HomeScreen

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, homescreen

After days of frustration--I'd like to ask-- is it even possible to add an `OnTouch Listener` to the Android Homescreen? (not any other custom Homescreen). First I get a `WindowsManager` and `WindowsManager Layout Parameters`. Then I create a new `LinearLayout`. I `AddView` with `LinearLayout` and `Layout Parameters`. I `setOnTouchListener` to the `LinearLayout`. Doesn't work.

Is there a combination of changes to the Manifest file, Layout xml file and code to get the Android Homescreen `OnTouchListener` to work?

Do I need to do an `OnInterceptTouchEvent` and run this on a non-UI thread? What do you recommend is the best way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It sounds kinda like a key logger.

Comment: I'd like to build functionality thats based on the type of touch the OnTouchListener detects on the Android Homescreen.

Comment: Like a Gesture Detector?

Comment: Is this your own home screen implementation? Or somebody else's?

Comment: Its just the basic Android homescreen. Just want to add OnTouchListener to the basic Android homescreen.

Comment: Hadn't really thought of it as a Gesture Detector-- do you have any suggestions along that line?